# How can I project texture on 3D model by using camera parameters?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, 3d-modelling

I have a 3D model (in PLY format), its original images and camera parameters (Focal length, principal points, Lens distortions, and aspect ratio). What application is suitable for projecting texture on models?
I want to know whether camera parameters are valid or not.

Comment: I think you have to be a little more specific: how it is made your .ply model? Where i comes from? It has surfaces, only points? What type of textures? (maybe you can post some image?). In theory you could consider to use a programming language and modify point - by - point your 3D model. In this way you (if you have points, not faces) can use the projection equation to project 3d points into pixel and see if your image is correctly reconstructed, or reverse the process and add your texture.

Comment: I have both surface and points. I project images on mesh. I use an opensource library and I set camera parameters. I do not know whether camera parameter is wrong or source code! I have changed camera parameters to insert images in correct places, but I could not achieve good results. I need a method or application which get mesh and camera parameters and apply texture on mesh.